# Как вытащить правильно массив

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как извлечь данные через foreach? на выходе получается неподходящий для этого объект. Нужно, чтобы можно было сделать key => value, при том только [mg_id] и [mg_name]. Я совсем запутался, получается что угодно, но не то, что нужно.

```
<?php
    $zquery = ('SELECT * FROM maingroups;');
    $zstmt = $pdo->prepare($zquery);
    $zstmt->execute();
    $zresults = $zstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($zresults);
    ?>
```

На выходе

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [mg_id] => 1 [mg_name] => 3 - 5 лет [mg_ico] => svg/user1.svg ) [1] => Array ( [mg_id] => 2 [mg_name] => 6 - 9 лет [mg_ico] => ) [2] => Array ( [mg_id] => 3 [mg_name] => 10 - 15 лет [mg_ico] => ) )
```

Comment: Вполне подходящий, иначе у Вас поля заполнятся значениями последнего элемента из БД. Запускайте foreach, и в каждой итерации у Вас будут доступны поля с уникальными значениями.

Comment: `foreach($zresults as $i){ здесь $i как один елемент массива }`, вроде так.. ну там в выводе  своё

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($zresults as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value["mg_id"], $value["mg_name"]);
}
```